# Can combine granuar and aggregated data for regression analysis?

Tags: regression, time-series, survey

I have survey data conducted across several countries. The survey is repeated every 5-odd years - the participants are chosen randomly each time - it is not a panel, but the survey questions remain largely the same. So from this survey I have individual level data on some beliefs (independent variables).

I have country's level data (yearly) on behaviors/consumption (dependent variable).

Is there a way to standardize/normalize/do magic somehow to use the survey level data to check the impact of beliefs on behavior?

Or must I collapse the survey data on beliefs to country level and then run time series at country level?